# Keeping in a list a list of recent insertions/removal to/from a list of lists

Tags: trees, arrays, lists

I have a list of lists T.

I stress test my database software by randomly adding and removing sublists and elements of sublists to/from T and from/to my database. (After this I compare T with the database, because they must be identical, because they underwent the same sequence of insertions/deletions.)

I want the random generator more often to do operations correlating with recent operations: e.g. if I recently inserted an element to a sublist, then element deletion operation should with higher probability delete element of this sublist (rather than an other, arbitrary element), and sublist deletion operation should with higher probability delete the sublist containing this element (than to delete another sublist). This is useful to make race conditions during testing more likely.

So, I want to keep a list of recent insertions/deletions and more likely choose the list head (and elements nearby to the head) than an arbitrary element of the list. I want a guidance on how to program this efficiently.

The above was my real problem. The below is its XY-problem (internals of my thinking):

I need an efficient implementation for the following data structure:

- It is a list L of pointers (or equivalently, of keys in a map structure) pointing to another data structure (not important which).
- It has the operation to append a pointer.

  - (optionally, not sure how it's better with or without this rule) when a pointer appended, the members of the list equal to it are removed (so, probably, keeping the invariant of no duplicates in the list L).
- It has an operation to delete a certain pointer (identified by what it points to, not by the number in the list L, that is by its value rather than by its index) from the list L. (This is useful to delete from L pointers to deleted sublists or elements of T.)

So I keep the list (with or without duplicates, not yet decided) and with higher probability choose its head.

The main problem is that when deleting from the list of lists T, I need also to delete from the list L, and I currently have no solution how to do this efficiently.

I also want advice whether to allow or not duplicates in L.

Comment: Another idea is to add to T information about the locations in L (an element index, if L is represented as an array). Then removal from L would take O(N) time where N is length of L.

Comment: But when I delete a lists from T, it requires deletion of all pointers to the elements of deleted list. That is not very efficient. Is there a more efficient solution?